# Error en el Modo Oscuro en Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, función-personalizada, modificaciones

Necesito vuestra ayuda, y es que estoy haciendo modo oscuro en mi programa Python. En este caso, el color de los números y letras es negro por defecto. Pero cuando cambio a modo oscuro, en la sección de precio que se actualiza cada 5 segundos debe ser blanco, ya que el fondo es negro, al principio el precio es blanco, pero cuando se actualiza cada 5 segundos, se vuelve negro, y no se cual es el error.

```
is_dark_mode = False

def toggle_dark_mode():
    global is_dark_mode

    if is_dark_mode:
        root.configure(background="white")
        price_label.config(bg="white")
        text_label.config(bg="white")
        min_label.config(bg="white")
        min_entry.config(fg="black", bg="#F2F2F2")
        max_label.config(bg="white")
        max_entry.config(fg="black", bg="#F2F2F2")
        button_container.config(bg="white")
        confirm_button.config(style="TButton")
        reset_button.config(style="TButton")
        is_dark_mode = False
    else:
        root.configure(background="#222222")
        price_label.config(bg="#222222", fg="white")
        text_label.config(bg="#222222", fg="white")
        min_label.config(bg="#222222", fg="white")
        min_entry.config(fg="white", bg="#444444")
        max_label.config(bg="#222222", fg="white")
        max_entry.config(fg="white", bg="#444444")
        button_container.config(bg="#222222")
        confirm_button.config(style="TButton", fg="white", bg="#444444")
        reset_button.config(style="TButton", fg="white", bg="#444444")
        is_dark_mode = True


def toggle_normal_mode():
    global is_dark_mode

    if is_dark_mode:
        root.configure(background="#222222")
        price_label.config(bg="#222222", fg="white")
        text_label.config(bg="#222222", fg="white")
        min_label.config(bg="#222222", fg="white")
        min_entry.config(fg="white", bg="#444444")
        max_label.config(bg="#222222", fg="white")
        max_entry.config(fg="white", bg="#444444")
        button_container.config(bg="#222222")
        confirm_button.config(style="Round.TButton", fg="white", bg="#444444")
        reset_button.config(style="Round.TButton", fg="white", bg="#444444")
        is_dark_mode = True
    else:
        # Restaurar apariencia por defecto en modo normal
        root.configure(background="white")
        price_label.config(bg="white")
        text_label.config(bg="white", fg="black")
        min_label.config(bg="white", fg="black")
        min_entry.config(fg="black", bg="#F2F2F2")
        max_label.config(bg="white", fg="black")
        max_entry.config(fg="black", bg="#F2F2F2")
        button_container.config(bg="white")
        confirm_button.config(style="Round.TButton")
        reset_button.config(style="Round.TButton")
        is_dark_mode = False
```

Aqui dejo una pequeña captura donde el precio esta de color negro.
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Podrías agregar un código donde el comportamiento inesperado ocurra por favor? Sin eso, esto es jugar a las adivinanzas. Y mi intento de adivinar es: Tengo la suposición de que cambias el color del texto a negro cuando mandas a actualizar el precio. Los programas no siguen caprichos. Si cambia a negro, es por que se lo pides en algún lado.

Comment: Ya lo he modificado, he subido una pequeña captura, donde se muestra que el precio esta de color negro, cuando deberia ser blanco en el modo oscuro

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Este es la solución del código, por lo visto era una fallo de los colores definidos, al parecer estaban invertidos por lo que hacia el mal funcionamiento del código

```
is_dark_mode = False

def toggle_dark_mode():
    global is_dark_mode

    if is_dark_mode:
        # Restaurar apariencia por defecto en modo normal
        root.configure(background="white")
        price_label.config(bg="white", fg="black")
        text_label.config(bg="white", fg="black")
        min_label.config(bg="white", fg="black")
        min_entry.config(fg="black", bg="#F2F2F2")
        max_label.config(bg="white", fg="black")
        max_entry.config(fg="black", bg="#F2F2F2")
        button_container.config(bg="white")
        confirm_button.config(style="Round.TButton")
        reset_button.config(style="Round.TButton")
        is_dark_mode = False
    else:
        root.configure(background="#222222")
        price_label.config(bg="#222222", fg="white")
        text_label.config(bg="#222222", fg="white")
        min_label.config(bg="#222222", fg="white")
        min_entry.config(fg="white", bg="#444444")
        max_label.config(bg="#222222", fg="white")
        max_entry.config(fg="white", bg="#444444")
        button_container.config(bg="#222222")
        confirm_button.config(style="TButton", fg="white", bg="#444444")
        reset_button.config(style="TButton", fg="white", bg="#444444")
        is_dark_mode = True


def toggle_normal_mode():
    global is_dark_mode

    if is_dark_mode:
        root.configure(background="#222222")
        price_label.config(bg="#222222", fg="white")
        text_label.config(bg="#222222", fg="white")
        min_label.config(bg="#222222", fg="white")
        min_entry.config(fg="white", bg="#444444")
        max_label.config(bg="#222222", fg="white")
        max_entry.config(fg="white", bg="#444444")
        button_container.config(bg="#222222")
        confirm_button.config(style="Round.TButton", fg="white", bg="#444444")
        reset_button.config(style="Round.TButton", fg="white", bg="#444444")
        is_dark_mode = True
    else:
        # Restaurar apariencia por defecto en modo normal
        root.configure(background="white")
        price_label.config(bg="white", fg="black")
        text_label.config(bg="white", fg="black")
        min_label.config(bg="white", fg="black")
        min_entry.config(fg="black", bg="#F2F2F2")
        max_label.config(bg="white", fg="black")
        max_entry.config(fg="black", bg="#F2F2F2")
        button_container.config(bg="white")
        confirm_button.config(style="Round.TButton")
        reset_button.config(style="Round.TButton")
        is_dark_mode = False
```

Comment: Por lo general las respuestas que tienen solo código son consideradas de baja calidad, pues carecen de una explicación de cómo ese código resuelve el problema planteado por la pregunta. Aún si respondes tu propia pregunta, estás respondiendo a la comunidad y especialmente a los futuros visitantes de este hilo. Por favor agrega dicha explicación. Para más información lee [answer]. Un saludo.